# Mixed and pure states statistical mechanics exercise

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

I'm studying quantum statistical mechanics and I have a problem figuring out how to do an exercise. I have understood the difference between pure and mixed state using the density matrix formalism but I have difficulty in understanding how to carry out the following:

"Design an experiment which is able to distinguish from:

1. the quantum mixture $\rho_*=\begin{bmatrix}
   |\alpha|^2 & \alpha\beta^*  \\
   \alpha^*\beta & |\beta|^2 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$
2. the classical mixture $\rho_*=\begin{bmatrix}
   |\alpha|^2 & 0\\
   0 & |\beta|^2 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$ "

Could someone give me some suggestions or help me think it through?
Thanks in advance.
I hope I have expressed myself clearly and not made any mistakes. This is the first time I have used this site.

Comment: Hint: what do the off diagonal terms of the density matrix represent?

Answer (score 1):

Measurements in the density matrix formalism correspond to expectation values of observables. These are given by the trace of the observable times density matrix: $\langle A \rangle := \text{tr}(A\rho)$.

Finding an experiment that distinguishes the systems means "finding $A$ such that $\langle A \rangle_{qm} \neq \langle A \rangle_{cl}$ (where you use the quantum and classical mixture).

I don't know if you are supposed to give physical meaning to the observable $A$.